# Hints on solving the equation $3\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{3x+1}=2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I recently stumbled upon the problem $3\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{3x+1}=2$, where I am supposed to solve the equation for x. My problem with this equation though, is that I do not know where to start in order to be able to solve it. Could you please give me a hint (or two) on what I should try first in order to solve this equation?

**Note** that I only want hints.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT**

We have

$$\sqrt a + \sqrt b=c \stackrel{both \, terms\, \ge 0}\iff (\sqrt a + \sqrt b)^2=a+2\sqrt{ab}+b=c^2 $$

and

$$a+2\sqrt{ab}+b=c^2 \color{red}{\implies} (2\sqrt{ab})^2=(c^2-a-b)^2$$

for the latter implication we need to check at the end for possible extra solutions.

Comment: I would use "$\implies$" instead of "$\iff$" since $(\sqrt1+\sqrt1)^2=(-2)^2$ but $\sqrt1+\sqrt1\not=-2$.

Comment: @BarryCipra Yes of course! SInce in the first all quantities are positive, I think that it is required ony at the second step. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, if you have $c\ge0$ then the first "$\iff$" is correct.

Comment: @BarryCipra Exactly, I fix accordingly! Thanks, Bye.

Comment: @BarryCipra I agree with you! Some readers may find the discussion worthwhile. Thanks again, Bye.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Try the substitution $u=\sqrt{x-1}$.

**Added later**: The answer hints so far, including mine (above), have all aimed at squaring away the square root symbols, leaving a quadratic equation  that's easy to solve, with the caveat that the solutions to the quadratic are not necessarily solutions to the original equation. That approach works for any equation of the form $A\sqrt{ax+b}+B\sqrt{cx+d}=C$. But for this specific equation, it turns out there's an easy solution. Since the OP has asked only for hints, I'll state the key idea in the form of a question:

> What can you say about $3\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{3x+1}$ if $x\gt1$?

Comment: That doesn't help because the other square root is $\sqrt{3x+1}$.

Comment: @user247327, $u=\sqrt{x-1}\implies x=u^2+1\implies\sqrt{3x+1}=\ldots$.

Comment: Ah, I see that the idea in what I just added was already in Batominovski's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to what others have said but I think a little simpler:  write $3\sqrt{x- 1}+ \sqrt{3x+ 1}= 2$ as $3\sqrt{x- 1}= 2- \sqrt{3x+ 1}$ and square both sides: $9(x- 1)= 4- 4\sqrt{3x+ 1}+ 3x+ 1$.  Now write that as $6x- 14= -4\sqrt{3x+ 1}$ and square again: $36x^2- 168x+ 196= 16(3x+ 1)= 48x+ 16$.

$36x^2- 120x+ 180= 0$.

$3x^2- 10x+ 15= 0$.

Of course, squaring twice might have introduced "spurious" solutions so solve that quadratic equation and check the solutions in the original equation.

Comment: $-168-48\not=-120$.

Comment: That’s the way I always handle these problems.

Answer (score 1):

**First step**

$$3\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{3x+1}=2\implies (3\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{3x+1})^2=2^2.$$

**Second step**

After rearranging you'll get

$$6\sqrt{x-1}\sqrt{3x+1}=ax+b.$$ Take squares one more time.

**Final step**

Solve the quadratic equation and check that the solutions you get are solutions of the initial equation.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A:=\sqrt{3x+1}$ and $B:=\sqrt{3x-3}$.  Then, $A+\sqrt{3}B=2$ and $A^2-B^2=4$.  That is,
$$(A+\sqrt{3}B)^2=A^2-B^2\,.$$

> Suppose that we are solving over the reals.  Thus, $\left(2\sqrt{3}A+4B\right)\,B=0$.  Since $A$ and $B$ are nonnegative and cannot simultaneously be $0$, we conclude that $B=0$.

---

Alternatively, we note that $x\geq 1$ so that $\sqrt{x-1}$ is a real number.  Thus, $$\sqrt{3x+1}\geq \sqrt{3\cdot 1+1}=2\,.$$  For the required equality to hold, we must then have $\sqrt{3x+1}=2$.  Therefore, ....

Answer (score 1):

Put $f(x) := 3\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{3x+1}$ on $[1,\infty)$. Then $f'(x) > 0$ and $f(1) = 2$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :**

Let,$$x=t^2+1$$
So, $$3t+\sqrt{3t^2+4}=2$$
$$\implies 3t^2+4=(2-3t)^2$$

Now,it's your turn to go on...

The answer should be $$x=1,if~t=0$$

$$and$$ $$x=5,if~t=2$$

Answer (score 0):

$$3\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{3x+1}=2$$
this equation is defined for $$x\geq 1$$
$$9(x-1)+6\sqrt{(x-1)(3x+1)}+3x+1=4$$
$$12x+6\sqrt{(x-1)(3x+1)}=12$$
$$2x+\sqrt{(x-1)(3x+1)}=2$$
$$\sqrt{(x-1)(3x+1)}=2-2x ; 0\leq x\leq1$$
$$(x-1)(3x+1)=4(1-x)^2$$
$$(x-1)(3x+1+4-4x)=0$$
$$(x-1)(-x+5)=0$$
$$x=1$$
I know there is something wrong with my solution, but I hope someone will help to make it clear and correct any mistake.